# Kotlin how to split a list in to sublists

Tags: kotlin, split

I would like to split a list into a few sublists, but I have no idea how to do it.
Once of my ideas was splitting the list by index of element. For exmaple "B" index is 0, "S" index 2, so I would like to take a part between index 0 - 1 into the first sublist, then the second sublist should be the part between index 2 - 5.
Example of my list:

```
val listOfObj = listOf("B", "B" , "S", "B", "B", "X", "S", "B", "B", "P")
```

Result after splitting:

```
listOf(listOf("B","B"), listOf("S", "B", "B", "X"), listOf("S", "B", "B", "P") )
```

How do I achieve such a result?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/sub-list.html

Comment: I tried use sublist, but I have no idea how to do it. I would like to create each  new sublist before char "S", so I got indexes of this chars and I tried do it in foreach loop, but it not work correct :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it goes. I wrote it from my phone without checking but the idea is basic.

```
val result = mutableListOf<List<String>>()
var current = mutableList<String>()
listOfObj.forEach { letter ->
  if (letter == "S") {
    result.add(current)
    current = mutableListOf<String>()
  }
  current.add(letter)
}
if (current.isNotEmpty()) {
  result.add(current)
}
```

You can even create an extension function for a `List<T>` that gets a separator element as a parameter and returns a list of lists.